In Intersteller why didn't Murph forgive Cooper (refuse to send messages as an adult)
In the film 'Interstellar,' Murph initially refuses to send messages to her father, Cooper, both as a child and as an adult. As a child, her reasons for not forgiving him are clear:

Cooper's uncertain return: Cooper doesn't know when he'll be back.
Secrecy about departure: Cooper can't disclose why he's leaving, citing the need to protect his children.
Disregard for Murph's efforts: Despite Murph's scientific breakthrough in decoding the "STAY" message, Cooper departs.

The below reasoning also is assumed before Dr Brand on his death bed and his confession.
My confusion lies in Murph's continued refusal to communicate with Cooper as an adult, knowing that Cooper left to save humanity, why doesn't Murph, now a scientist herself, reconcile with him and send messages?
I understand her initial anger as a child, lacking full comprehension of the situation. But as an adult scientist, shouldn't she recognize Cooper's sacrifice and reach out to him? Any insights or interpretations on this?

Because she's stubborn. It's literally her defining feature
